# Prevent File Explorer displaying Navigation pane from Excel hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-explorer

I prefer not to use the navigation pane. Settings are such that when opening files from folders etc it does not get displayed.

But when I click a cell in an Excel worksheet containing a link to a local file or folder, File Explorer **always** comes up with it displayed. How do I prevent that please?

Using Excel 365 and Win 10 Pro Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1023)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to locate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Explore`, then rename **LaunchExplorerFlags** to **LaunchExplorerFlags-Old** in the right-pane.
Please note, before modify the registry key, you'd better [back it up first](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch Emily, that seems to have done it!